# Why does UTF-8 waste so many bits?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

If you look at the [table here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) which shows the byte layout of UTF-8, it looks quite wasteful!

A 6-byte char has 17 hardcoded bits! If we just set the first bit of each byte to `1` to indicate "the next byte is part of the same char" then we would only require 6 bits:

```
1xxxxxxx 1xxxxxxx 1xxxxxxx 1xxxxxxx 1xxxxxxx 0xxxxxxx
```

*And* it would *still* be backwards-compatible with ASCII! *And* we wouldn't be capped at 6 bytes either.

So why is UTF-8 wasteful? Surely there must be reason that I'm not seeing. Moreover, it seems like there's enough information in that first byte that we don't even need the `10` header on each of the remaining bytes. We could have done

```
0xxxxxxx
10xxxxxx xxxxxxxx
110xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
1110xxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
11110xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
11111xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
```

And that would have worked too, no? Or we could support even more bytes with a different scheme.

Does it have to do with how those single bytes will be displayed if UTF-8 isn't properly supported? What does `10` afford? And is the trade-off worth it? If I try to render UTF-8 encoded Japanese characters in an ASCII-only program, I'm going to get garbage either way aren't I?

Comment: Something tells this would be more appropriate on Programmers. It's more a theory question than a specific problem.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I thought so too, but then I found another question about UTF-8 being limited to 1 byte here, so.. *shrug*

Comment: Derp...just found the same question asked on progammers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/262227/7390

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this redundancy is to make UTF-8 self-synchronizing: the symbol stream formed by a portion of one code word, or by the overlapped portion of any two adjacent code words, is not a valid code word. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-synchronizing_code and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#History

Comment: Hah. That's interesting. I started thinking about how I would change my scheme to make it self-synchronising I ended up with UTF-8. I guess that explains it then.

Comment: Why is self synchronization useful though? Also, is the first proposal from the question not self synchronizing?

Comment: Not sure how relevant the error discovery aspects are in todays typical use cases. The first proposal would not be self synchronizing as it wouldn't be possible to distinguish a correct 2-byte code from a 3-byte code with the first byte missing (I guess some kind of start/end marker scheme could do this though)